# XPages - Data binding issue

Tags: xpages

I am having issues computing a data binding field name. I don't receive any errors, however the radio button is in a "disabled" state. When I put simple data binding on that I know works, the radio loses it "disabled" state and works as expected, but obviously doesn't save to the field name I want. The end goal is to build a field name based on the combination of 2 custom properties. I've tried a variation of things, some of which are shown below:

```
1.    compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName #compositeData.radio1LabelText]

    2. compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName+compositeData.radio1LabelText]

    3. compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName,compositeData.radio1LabelText]

    4. try{
        var fieldName:string=compositeData.fieldName;
        var fieldLabel:string=compositeData.radio1LabelText;
        return compositeData.dataSource+"."+fieldName+fieldLabel;   
    }catch(e){
        openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
    }

5. compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName += compositeData.radio1LabelText]

6.compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName.concat(compositeData.radio1LabelText)]
```

Thanks

**UPDATE in regards comments chat with Jesse:**

```
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
                        value="#{javascript:compositeData.labels}" var="rptLabels">
                        <tr>
<td>
<xp:panel>
<xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="concatRadioName1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var tmpString = "GIMS"+rptLabels+"Self";
var fieldName = tmpString.replace(/\s+/g, '');
print(fieldName);
return fieldName
}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
</xp:this.dataContexts>
                        <xp:radioGroup styleClass="no-margin">


                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{compositeData.dataSource[concatRadioName1]}]]></xp:this.value>

                            <xp:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel=""></xp:selectItem>
                            <xp:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel=""></xp:selectItem>
                            <xp:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel=""></xp:selectItem>
                        </xp:radioGroup>
</xp:panel>

</td>

            </tr>
                    </xp:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, EL in XPages doesn't have a string concatenation operator, which makes this sort of thing tricky. Off the top of my head, I can think of two potential routes that could work:

- Inside the custom control, you could have a `dataContext` that concatenates the two properties, like `<xp:dataContext var="concatFieldName" value="#{compositeData.fieldName}#{compositeData.radio1LabelText}"/>`. Then, you could use `#{compositeData.dataSource[concatFieldName]}` later on in the page.
- If the values are either hard-coded on the calling page or can be computed using ${}-binding, you could use SSJS to generate a binding, similar to what you tried in #4 there. You could put the SSJS computation in a ${} binding, and then have the output be a string version of the #{} binding for the concatenated string. When you do a chain like that, the runtime will end up resolving the inner runtime binding properly.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I was really struggling with the concatenation, as using the + operator kept coming up with an error regarding converting string to long as its treated arithmetically.  Using the dataContext you suggested works. I've never used dataContext before so will do some reading up on it. Thanks again

Comment: Interesting question for you in regards something I am thinking for alter in development of my current project. But if I have a repeat control, with radio button groups, and the labels are passed in as a custom property in an array, then repeated.... If I wanted to bind each radiogroup, namedafter its label name, and then something appended. ie. labelONE, labelTWO etc how would this work? Can I do something like the above with the dataContext but in relation to the repeat and the var I reference it from?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the final aim is. When you say "label", is that referring to part of the field name you're binding to, as in the original code, or labels for the radio button options?

Comment: I just gave it a go and all looked fine until I hit save and I got the error javax.faces.FacesException: Error testing property 'GIMSShareSelf' in bean of type null. I've updated my question with new code as its easier to read

Comment: Hmm, well, it sounds like the field-name-computation logic is fine, but `compositeData.dataSource` is coming through as null. There may be trouble in the surrounding code that's passing in the data source.

Comment: Jesse you're a lifesaver! This was a new custom control where I hadn't created the custom property for the datasource yet!  As you say, code was fine but but there was no data source! Thanks!